# Can a trigger function in one database access table in another database?

Tags: mysql

I have two database (connections to two servers), database1 and database2. Is there a way for a trigger function in a table in database1 to access a table in database2? If this is possible, how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Mysql Federated Engine, then the answer is yes.

[How to create linked server MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370970/how-to-create-linked-server-mysql)

Best regards

Comment: Isn't that for separate servers? I think the OP is talking about different databases on the same server.

Comment: Yes, the question was edited, now it states clearly "connections to two servers".

Comment: Aah, I missed that bit, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about triggers, but in normal queries you can just use the databasename.tablename syntax.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `DatabaseA`.`Table1` t1
INNER JOIN `DatabaseB`.`Table1` t2 ON (`t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`)
```

Comment: Ignore this, I missed the bit about two different servers.