# Stored procedure which affects 2 servers

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create a MYSQL Stored procedure when I insert data into the table, the data will get inserted in other server table too.

I know this is possible in ORACLE databases but I don't know if It works in MYSQL.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible in MySQL using following approaches:

1. **Table Federation:** Create a new federated table same as main table having `ENGINE=FEDERATED` which will have a MySQL connection string username password and host id of other server. Onother server you need to create a new user and give insert grants to this user.
   Write a `TRIGGER` on main table and `AFTER INSERT` on main table insert into federated table.
2. **Replication:** Setup a replication from server1 (MASTER) to server2 (SLAVE) and add this table in replication.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to replicate all data (in the table) between a number of databases periodically?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

or do you want to propagate an insert?

your answer may be in

[How to create linked server MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370970/how-to-create-linked-server-mysql)