# Optimal way to fill in missing values after a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, data-structures

I will simplify my problem to make the core issue clear: I have a query that does `TableA INNER JOIN TableB LEFT JOIN TableC`.

The result of the left join is that in the result set, two of the columns might have NULL values in some rows. To fill in the missing values I have to loop over the result set and query another database that has the data (so it is not possible to join
in the first place).

My question is: Is there a standard/optimised approach when we need to fill nulls of a result set after a left join?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `COALESCE(...)` ([MSDN - COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms190349.aspx)) instead.

You query will then look like:

```
select a, b, COALESCE(TableB.c, 'replacement value')
from TableA INNER JOIN TableB LEFT JOIN TableC ...
```

Add another join for your replacement table and put the column you want to replace `NULL` values in the `COALESCE` function in you don't want to use a static value.

Comment: But I don't have the replacement value.I need to fill it in but to do that I loop over the result set and query another db

Comment: You can create _linked server_ to join your external DB in the query (if the DB is on the same server: `otherDB.Schema.Table`).

Answer (score 1):

"To fill in the missing values I have to loop over the result set and query another database that has the data (so it is not possible to join in the first place)."

Consider a different solution then looping to fill in data.

1.Another database on the same server==easy. Just join using db.schema qualified names.

1. Another database on a another server, still possibly depending on you network topography. Then join using server.db.schema qualified names.
2. Consider replicating the data you need if you regularly need to do this.

Comment: I can join tables from different databases in different machines?

Comment: Yes. You can join across servers if they are linked. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

Comment: I am not using MS-SQL but MySQL

Comment: Jim. Sorry, I misread that, especially after seeing user3426870's comment above. MySQL's FEDERATED engine provides similar functionality. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370970/how-to-create-linked-server-mysql

Comment: I am using InnoDb.Thanks for mentioning this though. I did not know this