# Insert into MySQL from SQL Server database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a data base which is SQL Server 2005, and I want to move some data from a table in this database to a MySQL database which is running on different server.

Is there any way to do this without using java code and creating some job.

SQL (Server A) 
Table1

Move To

MySql (Server B)
Table2

Comment: This may start you in the right direction, but from what I read it's annoyingly non-trivial.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370970/how-to-create-linked-server-mysql

Comment: Try [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) and see [link](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/)

Comment: If your Java be handy, you could use JDBC to connect to both databases and do the transfer.  This of course would require both drivers.

Comment: See this [question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/need-to-migrate-sql-server-to-mysql)

Comment: Check this link. it might help..      https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html

Comment: I want to create a JOB on(SQL Server) which will automatically runs and insert into mysql running on other server.

Comment: You can do it with SSIS.

Comment: Rohitesh you need to Create a ssis package and create a  SQL server Agent Job add your package in job and execute the Job .

Comment: Pentaho data integration (kettle) can also easily do that. It is free and opensource.

Comment: Tab Alleman thanks i'll try this