# SQL Server Table to MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem when importing a table form SQL Server to MySQL.

This is what I do:

1. First I export a CSV file with the data of the table Clients from SQL Server.
2. Then I import that CSV file to an auxiliar table in MySQL.
3. Finaly, I execute a query to insert the new data into the Clients table from MySQL

Is there any way to automatize this process?  I've tried several methods, but it wasn't successful.  ( Methods such as link both servers and configure them. )

English is not my first language.

Kind regards.

Comment: don't use csv. it's a crap absolute-last-ditch-before-you-slit-your-wrists format. there's far better tools for export/import between disparate databases.

Comment: You should be able to create a linked server between them and execute your insert directly into MySQL.  Take this code once working and put it into a scheduled job.  Based on the questions wording I assume you are moving data from SQL Server to MySQL.

Comment: @MisterPositive Yes, that was exactly what I've tried, but could't make the conection from MySQL Workbench to SQL Server

Comment: I would recommend you debug making that connection.  Instead of pulling from MySQL you should be able to push from SQL Server as well.

Comment: What did you try to make the connection?  How did it fail?  Was there an error message?

Comment: @destination-data first I couldn't instal the odbc for MySQL, and the couldn't instal the MySQL Workbench

Comment: Why not?  Did the installs fail?  If so, did they return an error message?  The more detail you provide; the more likely you are to find the right answer.  Tip:  Add extra details to your question, not everyone reads all the comments.

Comment: @destination-data So, now I could isntall it, I needed to install c++ before. But still can't link the servers. Whe I choose data sourse in the obdc option, never apears MySQL

Comment: what do you mean by "automate"? A one-off for many tables, many databases, or do you mean periodic migrations of a single table, with incremental additions ("append to table")?

Comment: @destination-data Now I could make some progress, but still having problemes.  I can't create the linked server from SQL server, it sais that couldn't test the connection

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a linked server between them and execute your insert directly into MySQL. Take this code once working and put it into a scheduled job.

[MySQL Linked Server Set Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370970/how-to-create-linked-server-mysql)

Comment: I'm having troubles to create the linked server from SQL Server Management Studio