# How do I join tables using two database which are in different sql server in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, join, laravel-4

I am searching for a solution to join two tables from two db which are in two different connection. Is there any solution to join tables from different db which are in different connection.

I have following db connections

```
'connection1' => array(
                    'driver'    => 'mysql',
                    'host'      => '*****.*****.co.za',
                    'database'  => 'abc',
                    'username'  => 'root',
                    'password'  => '*****',
                    'charset'   => 'utf8',
                    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                    'prefix'    => '',
                ),

'connection2' => array(
                    'driver'    => 'mysql',
                    'host'      => '*****.*****.co.za',
                    'database'  => 'xyz',
                    'username'  => 'root',
                    'password'  => '********',
                    'charset'   => 'utf8',
                    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                    'prefix'    => '',
                ),
```

## For Example

I have a table called Tableone in the database abc which is in the connection "connection1" and another table called Tabletwo in the database xyz which is in the connection "connection2". So how I can join Tableone and Tabletwo? Can any one answer my question?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370970/how-to-create-linked-server-mysql#5371062

Comment: Is that possible to do with php laravel + xamp ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. I would assume that if you have enough control over the generated SQL then yes.