# CFQUERY update inner join two tables from separate servers

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfquery

I have this update statement -

```
<cfquery name="updateqry" datasource="thisone">
    update dbOne.tableA a
    inner join dbTwo.tableB b on a.docid=b.docid
    set a.download_dt = now(), a.document_status = "DOWNLOADED", a.rec_mod_dt = now()
    where b.school_id = <cfqueryparam value="#project.school_id#">
    and b.project_id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.project_id#">
    and date(b.doc_add_dt) >= <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.begin_dt#">
    and date(b.doc_add_dt) <= <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.end_dt#">
    and a.download_dt is null and a.document_status <> "DOWNLOADED"
</cfquery>
```

dbOne and dbTwo are on different servers now. How do I separate this update statement into multiple statements in order to get the info I need from each separate server's tables? I've never seen this update inner join syntax before, I'm really stumped.

Comment: read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370970/how-to-create-linked-server-mysql.  Set up the necessary linked servers and use them.

Comment: Set up trusted links between the servers. Check Dan's link.

Comment: assuming I am not the dba and I can't set up the linked server solution, does that make it absolutely impossible to execute a solution?

Comment: Get the dba to do it for you.  It's not the only solution, but it's the best one.

Comment: would another solution be to select what I need from tableB and loop through the result set and do an update on tableA with each result?

Comment: That would work, and it wouldn't be the end of the world for a few dozen records.  However, the more records you have, the worse this option becomes.